# Caffe net: multiple image input with one label

Tags: neural-network, hdf5, caffe

I am fine tuning a neural net that takes 2 input images, which are later concatenated. To fine tune, I would like to perform regression and add labels to this network.

How can I do this? Currently, the net uses an `ImageData` layer for input which I will have to change to `HDF5`. But how can I pass a single label to these two input channels?

I have looked around at how to do this and I found this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27436987/caffe-multiple-input-images). However, here they create a single HDF5 file with 2 input images. In my case, I'd have two HDF5 files with 1 input image, which are then concatenated and then has 1 to the same label.

Comment: you can put everything in a single HDF5 file with multiple datasets

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply! I have one more question: if I have `{"data1":[images], "data2":[images]}`, how can I pass labels?

Comment: why not `{"data1":[images], "data2":[images], "label":[labels]}`? You are not restricted to two datasets in a single HDF5 file...